# Information Retrieval - How can i process search query with single word break'ed into multiple tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, information-retrieval

I am just a beginner in information retrieval.

I am looking to solve a problem where a user mistakenly adds a space between the characters while typing a word or joins two words into one, which as of now fails to process because of simple inverted index lookup.

Let say i have inverted index the following documents:

1. Jack and Jill are good friends.
2. Jack went to Alaska.
3. Jill lives in New York.

Now Having a inverted index means like having **new** and **york** indexed as separate tokens (Assuming just as a example and no NLP being used to tag New York as Location)

```
token    count    location
jack      2          1,2
jill      2          1,2
new       1           3
york      1           3
alaska    1           4
```

Now for a Query **jack**, i will get locations 1,2 which is fine.

But for a query **newyork** (assuming the query is without space) how can i get **new york** from the index which will have location 3 (combined).

And also for a query **ala ska** (with space) how can i retrieve the token **alaska** (without space in index) respectively.

Any suggestions or any specific algorithms that i am missing out.

I am just a beginner to information retrieval.

Thank You for your help.

I am thinking of breaking each query token into character-gram combination and finally merge them to find out the most common tokens.

For example query **newyork**

> Find all the tokens of till limit n, starting with n... then ne....then new.... then newy.... etc, similarly like ne.. ew...wy..yo..or..rk...,
>
> which will finally after merging the array will get ***new*** and ***york*** somewhere..

Similarly with query **ala ska** (break'ed the word with space(s))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like that will work for you:

Create you index with a custom analyzer (**ngram** tokenizer)
[Read about NGram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

```
PUT /index
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "token": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "myanalyzer"
        },
        "location":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "myanalyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": []
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "symbol",
            "punctuation"
          ],
          "min_gram": "3",
          "type": "ngram",
          "max_gram": "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's **POST** new documents

```
POST index/doc
{
  "token": "alaska",
  "location":[4]
}

POST index/doc
{
  "token": "york",
  "location":[3]
}

POST index/doc
{
  "token": "new",
  "location":[3]
}

POST index/doc
{
  "token": "jack",
  "location":[1,2]
}

 POST index/doc
 {
   "token": "jill",
   "location":[1,2]
 }
```

Search:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "token": "ala ska"
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.9346048,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "index",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "z7hBMG4BXy8wPzqAcq-C",
        "_score": 1.9346048,
        "_source": {
          "token": "alaska",
          "location": [
            4
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer!. But do you know how the algorithm works or any documentation. Thank You

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html explain how ngram works. you can also use it if you want to implement an autocomplete search.